# memory leak in creating a buffer with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using pandas to do a ring buffer, but the memory use keeps growing. what am I doing wrong?

Here is the code (edited a little from the first post of the question):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import resource


tempdata = np.zeros((10000,3))
tdf = pd.DataFrame(data=tempdata, columns = ['a', 'b', 'c'])

i = 0
while True:
    i += 1
    littledf = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1000, 3), columns = ['a', 'b', 'c'])
    tdf = pd.concat([tdf[1000:], littledf], ignore_index = True)
    del littledf
    currentmemory = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
    if i% 1000 == 0:
        print 'total memory:%d kb' % (int(currentmemory)/1000)
```

this is what I get:

```
total memory:37945 kb
total memory:38137 kb
total memory:38137 kb
total memory:38768 kb
total memory:38768 kb
total memory:38776 kb
total memory:38834 kb
total memory:38838 kb
total memory:38838 kb
total memory:38850 kb
total memory:38854 kb
total memory:38871 kb
total memory:38871 kb
total memory:38973 kb
total memory:38977 kb
total memory:38989 kb
total memory:38989 kb
total memory:38989 kb
total memory:39399 kb
total memory:39497 kb
total memory:39587 kb
total memory:39587 kb
total memory:39591 kb
total memory:39604 kb
total memory:39604 kb
total memory:39608 kb
total memory:39608 kb
total memory:39608 kb
total memory:39608 kb
total memory:39608 kb
total memory:39608 kb
total memory:39612 kb
```

not sure if it's related to this:

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2659

Tested on MacBook Air with Anaconda Python

Comment: Weirdly, I copy and paste this code and no leak. 0.12 and 0.13rc.

Comment: I added what I get (and changed the code a little bit). do you get the same or different?

Comment: I get "total memory:59 kb" all the way down. Perhaps OS/setup, maybe add some more details :s. Could be better as a sep github issue though. Have you tried adding the gc.collect as in the other issue?

Comment: You may be right. I'm testing it on a Ubuntu server and memory seems to be staying the same...Weird

Comment: To locate the leak, try using [memory_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using *concat*, why not update the **DataFrame** in place?  `i % 10` will determine which 1000 row slot you write to each update.

```
i = 0
while True:
    i += 1
    tdf.iloc[1000*(i % 10):1000+1000*(i % 10)] = np.random.rand(1000, 3)
    currentmemory = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
    if i% 1000 == 0:
        print 'total memory:%d kb' % (int(currentmemory)/1000)
```